Is it possible to force Bluetooth connection of my headphones to the PC if they are already connected to my phone?
So, here is the question:
Windows 10 PC with Bluetooth.
Is it possible to force Bluetooth connection of my headphones to the PC if they are already connected to my phone?
If my headphones are already connected to my phone, they would not connect to the PC.
I have to disconnect them from the phone before trying to connect to the PC.
Is there a way to force them to connect to a PC automatically?
Thanks!

Some of the really cheap BlueTooth headphones have no security at all - they will auto pair as soon as one connection drops, probably not suitable for use in public, but I have a pair that does this for use around the house - your mileage will vary on this, since you need to play with them to figure out which device they "prefer" to pair with.


Is it possible to force Bluetooth connection of my headphones to the PC if they are already connected to my phone?

Unless the peripherals have been specifically designed to allow multiple connections - a feature that's becoming increasingly common with Bluetooth 5.x but still very niche -, pairing mean 1:1 only and there's no way to "force" multiple connections.

Understood, thank you!
